# Why do Vampires have to be invited into your home?

Tags: vampire, the-vampire-diaries, folklore, the-originals

Why do vampires have to be invited into your home? Is there a specific reason, or is it just some random thing someone made up?

Comment: What research have you done?  What have you learned from it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a old element of vampire folklore.  Although there were many variations on vampiric creatures, along with their powers and weaknesses, there were some fairly commonplace (but not universal) notions regarding them.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire):

> Apotropaics—items able to ward off revenants—are common in vampire folklore. Garlic is a common example, a branch of wild rose and hawthorn plant are said to harm vampires, and in Europe, sprinkling mustard seeds on the roof of a house was said to keep them away. Other apotropaics include sacred items, for example a crucifix, rosary, or holy water. Vampires are said to be unable to walk on consecrated ground, such as that of churches or temples, or cross running water.
>
> Although not traditionally regarded as an apotropaic, mirrors have been used to ward off vampires when placed, facing outwards, on a door (in some cultures, vampires do not have a reflection and sometimes do not cast a shadow, perhaps as a manifestation of the vampire's lack of a soul). This attribute is not universal (the Greek vrykolakas/tympanios was capable of both reflection and shadow), but was used by Bram Stoker in Dracula and has remained popular with subsequent authors and filmmakers.
>
> **Some traditions also hold that a vampire cannot enter a house unless invited by the owner; after the first invitation they can come and go as they please**. Though folkloric vampires were believed to be more active at night, they were not generally considered vulnerable to sunlight.

Another [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_vampire_traits_in_folklore_and_fiction) has a table of vampire traits in different folkloric sources and works of fiction—which includes whether or not an invitation is needed for a vampire to enter a dwelling as one of the table's columns.

Comment: I did a lot of reading on vampire folklore many years ago, tracking the tales backward across the Transylvanian alps and across southern Russia and that region.
One of the stories right before the stories got to the Transylvanian alps has someone under the sway of the vampire, letting them in through a window. There is no real indication that the victim had to invite it in, but the vampire required the victim to open the slats/window for it, even though it was obviously strong enough to force it (7-9ft tall). Maybe this is where it began?